# Google Cloud Build how to send context with different path to Docker build

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

I have these two docker containers that I need to build, `nginx` and `php-fpm`

However, both need to use the ROOT directory as context, and Google Cloud Build uses the nginx and php-fpm (the dirs where the Dockerfile is) as context.

How can I change that?

[image]

This is my cloudbuild.yaml file

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/monolito-arg-phpfpm', './infra/docker/php-fpm' ]
    id: 'Build Docker PHP-FPM image'
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/monolito-arg-nginx', './infra/docker/nginx' ]
    id: 'Build Docker nginx image'
images:
  - 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/monolito-arg/monolito-arg-phpfpm'
  - 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/monolito-arg/monolito-arg-nginx'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posting it as an answer to give it more visibility:

As stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68303511/google-cloud-build-how-to-send-context-with-different-path-to-docker-build#:%7E:text=i%20fixed%20it%2C%20i%20needed%20more%20parameters%20in%20the%20build%3A%20args%3A%20%5B%20%27build%27%2C%20%27-t%27%2C%20%27gcr.io%2F%24project_id%2Fmonolito-arg-phpfpm%27%2C%20%27-f%27%2C%20%27.%2Finfra%2Fdocker%2Fphp-fpm%2Fdockerfile%27%2C%20%27.%27%20%5D%20%E2%80%93):

To fix it you needed more parameters in the build:

```
args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/monolito-arg-phpfpm', '-f', './infra/docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile', '.' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dir](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#dir) option to customize your step context.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I added dir: '/workspace' and still in the Docker build of the image I do a `ls -la` and only see what is in the Dockerfile directory

Comment: From which folder are you running the gcloud build command on your workstation?

Comment: I fixed it, I needed more parameters in the build: `args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/monolito-arg-phpfpm', '-f', './infra/docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile', '.' ]`

Comment: @JorgeeFG Can you post the solution you found as an actual answer?